# How does the default_target_path work in a Silex Firewall?

Tags: php, silex

I have setup a firewall in Silex as follows:

```
$this -> register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/admin/login$'
        ),
        'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/admin.*$',
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/admin/login',
                'check_path' => '/admin/security/validate',
                'default_target_path' => "/admin",
                'always_use_default_target_path' => true
            ),
            'logout' => array(
                'logout_path' => '/admin/security/logout'
            ),
            'users' => $app -> share(function () use ($app) {
                return new \Turtle\Providers\UserProvider($app);
            })
        )
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(
        array('^/admin.*$', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    )
));
```

This works in that when I hit a page in the 'admin' area I get redirected to my login page.  However I have started to do some authorization in my custom AuththenticationSuccess handler.  I want to use the built in method `determineTargeUrl` to redirect on success but it keeps redirecting to '/'.

After some debugging I have found that the options in the object that the method uses has the following:

```
array (size=5)
  'always_use_default_target_path' => boolean false
  'default_target_path' => string '/' (length=1)
  'login_path' => string '/login' (length=6)
  'target_path_parameter' => string '_target_path' (length=12)
  'use_referer' => boolean false
```

Clearly this is not what I have set in my firewall.  It is my understanding that this should match what it is in the firewall that I have used when accessing the system.  The URL I used was 'http://localhost/admin'.

So how do I make it so that the options I have set in my firewall appear in the object so that I can use the determineTargetUrl?

Thanks lots, Russell

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that your login route is inside your secured area. You've defined your access rule as `^/admin.*$`. This means that any route starting with `/admin` requires `ROLE_ADMIN` including your login route. To fix this you need to remove security from your login route.

Add a new access rule above your admin rule.

```php
'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/admin/login$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
    array('^/admin.*$', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
)
```

**Edit**: After reading your question again, I may have misunderstood you. it sounds like you can successfully log in but are redirected to the wrong place after a successful login. Is that correct? If so I will remove this answer.

Comment: Yeah, I can log in without issue, it is the redirect that is wrong.  It does not seem to be picking up the 'default_target_path' I have set.  I modified my access.rules so that the login page has IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY as it is probably more correct like that.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake.  I am using custom AuthenticationSuccess and AuthenticationFailure handlers and i neglected to pass any options into them when I was declaring them:

```
    $app['security.authentication.success_handler.admin'] = $app -> share(function() use ($app) {
        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler($app['security.http_utils'], array(), $app);
    });

    $app['security.authentication.failure_handler.admin'] = $app -> share(function() use ($app) {
        return new AuthenticationFailureHandler($app['kernel'], $app['security.http_utils'], array(), $app);
    });
```

So the options array that is used in `determineTargetUrl` on authentication success was empty and thus had default values.

By adding an array of options to the AuthenticationSuccessHandler it works.  This is OK as each custom handler is linked to a different firewall.